# Apache ignite connecting to different servers

Tags: ignite

I am using apache ignite with default configurations. I have two development server A and B where each server has the same code. I have 3 ignite nodes started on each server. 3 ignite nodes on A and 3 on B

I have created a ignite cache " ignite-bridg". Since on one server each node would create a cache and partition the data and these two servers are isolated so nothing will happen.

However I see that both the servers form a cluster and 6 nodes get connected. This is highly problematic for me. I think this is happening because both servers are accidently on same multicast group.

How to resolve this problem. I need to rectify it quickly

Comment: I want that only nodes in current server connects and form cluster

Answer (score 2):

By default Ignite uses Multicast IP finder (`TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder`) for nodes discovery process, in your case you should use Static IP finder (`TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder`) instead. By using it you could specify different lists of IP addresses for each server and form two clusters instead of one.

Here is more information regarding Static IP Finder configuration:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#static-ip-finder

Comment: Thanks Igor . I tried initially by giving localhost IP only 127.0.0.1 but it did not work . After adding port as well and giving ranges it worked